# Changing Text based off Positive or Negative value

Tags: excel

I'm creating a spreadsheet for the kids as a chore roster with payment and suggested saving and pays, and with fines for not doing the things they are supposed to. What I'm running into is I want their sheet to tell them how much they should save or how much they owe, what I'm using is

```
=IF(ABS(F4),E2 = "Should Save", E2 = "Owed")
```

The desired output is if their total is in the positive it should tell them what they should save from it and if it's negative tell them that they owe. Anyone know why that doesn't work and just shows that it's an invalid syntax?

Comment: `ABS` will eliminate the signage of the value in `F4` and return a positive value. You state you want to check if the total is positive or negative in the condition. Please could you edit your question to clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't set the value of another cell from a formula (if thats what you're trying to do?) and ABS will always returns a positive value, read here https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/abs.php

Just check the value against 0 instead, so in `E2` put

```
=IF(F4>0, "Should Save", IF(F4<0, "Owed", ""))
```

This is blank for 0 values.